# Calling delegate method blocks my C# app

Tags: c#, delegates

I have written a program that counts and the value is represented in the label's text. 
The process is started by clicking on the button.
When I start, UI freezes. 
I want to solve it by delegate.
Where is my bug?

Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{

    public delegate void MyDelegate();
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void DelegateMethod()
        {


            for (int i = 0; i < 9999999999999; i++)
            {
                label1.Text = i.ToString();

            }
            MessageBox.Show("OK");

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new MyDelegate(DelegateMethod));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It blocks because you are running it on the same thread as the UI. Also, that many updates to a label will not exactly perform very well - even if being updated from another thread.

If you really want to do that, create a new thread/task and invoke the UI update properly from there.

Answer (score 1):

It was because your UI element is getting updated so frequently and it will keep doing until loop terminates, if you add `Thread.Sleep()` after every iteration you can see the behaviour different:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9999999999999; i++)
{
    label1.Text = i.ToString();
    // for example delay 1 second
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

}
```

A more better approach is to use `async` and `await` keywords introduced in c# which will do extra work in background, not on UI thread, currently all the processing is getting done on your UI thread, which is causing UI thread to get blocked.But in your case that will not make difference, because here the problem is updating UI very fast which causes it to freeze.

Comment: I disagree - sleeping in the UI thread won't make the UI responsive, and neither `async` nor `await` will push work to a background thread.

Comment: yes in this case that does not matters, its loop that's problem

Comment: If the loop was run on a background thread and the label updating marshalled to the UI thread by `BeginInvoke`, then the sleep would help by throttling the background thread. Here, `Thread.Sleep` would worsen things, because it halts the UI thread.

Comment: agree, the purpose of Sleep here is so that label updated content gets visible whatever is in i

Answer (score 0):

Because you do it on the UI-Thread. Try `Task.Run()` instead of `BeginInvoke()`.